# External table is not in the expected format IIS Web Application problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, iis, oledbconnection

I have a strange error when trying to import data from files .xlsx from a web application vb.net from an "EXISTING" xlsx file with data inside. The error is throw when the action on my connection object open() is called.

> The error is : System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: External table is not
>   in the expected format.”

I have an application Winform who connect to a xlsx excel file and import data with the connection with no problems, the app is compile in x86 (32 bits):

> MyConnectionDataExcel.ConnectionString
>   =("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & TxtSourceString & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'")

When I'm doing the same thing in a web application, it return me the error : 
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: External table is not in the expected format.”

I try all sort of thing, like to compile my application in 32 bits (x86), in 64 bits(x64).

> I try to install this database engine 2010 :
>   https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=13255 and
>   this : https://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/download/details.aspx?id=10910

I enabled too on IIS the 32 bits on my application pool.

My virtual machine is on Windows server 2012.

I found a lot of posts around that subject but no post to really help me out.
It is working for .xls files tough but not with .xlsx files.
I can call the command open when I set an other path for the file xlsx (Like a file that does'nt exist). It then create an empty file.. but that's not what I want... I want to load data from a xlsx file.

Thanks you a lot...

Comment: A OleCommand has 3 types : cmd.CommandType =   CommandType.Text, CommandType.TableDirect, CommandType.StoredProcedure.  It sound like you are using the wrong type.  If you are using a SQL Query you probably need to use TEXT.

Comment: Is it possible that your xlsx is in a newer format which cannot be read by Excel 2010?   Try the newest ACE redistributable for 2016. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

Comment: I already try the version 2016 64 bits and 32 bits...  not working. Like I said it's working with a Winform vb application with the same code ... my connection is like that  Dim MyConnectionDataExcel As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection   MyConnectionDataExcel.ConnectionString = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= C:\GIDD.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;")    MyConnectionDataExcel.Open()